# Python Requests encountering status code 406 and error message "Request Not Allowed"

Tags: python, python-requests, web-crawler, fetch

When using POST method to acquire data from tokopedia.com, I got the response.json() as:

`[{'errors': [{'message': 'Request not allowed', 'extensions': {}}]}]`

I tried saving this by replacing 'https' with 'http', which used to work in this case, and using JavaScript fetch to do the same jobs. Both failed to resolve this issue.

This is the headers of mine:

```
headers = {
    'user-agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.67 Safari/537.36",
    'cookie': cookie,
    'origin': 'https://www.tokopedia.com',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'referer': 'https://www.tokopedia.com/p/dapur/aksesoris-dapur',
    'content-length': '25794'
};
```

And this is the headers from Chrome's DevTools:

```
:authority: gql.tokopedia.com
:method: POST
:path: /
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
content-length: 3206
content-type: application/json
cookie: cookie
origin: https://www.tokopedia.com
referer: https://www.tokopedia.com/p/dapur/aksesoris-dapur
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
tkpd-userid: 0
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.67 Safari/537.36
x-device: desktop-0.0
x-source: tokopedia-lite
x-tkpd-lite-service: zeus
```

And here is the main part of my code:

```
import requests

headers = headers
payload = [{'operationName': 'SearchProductQuery', 'variables': {'params': '&ob=23&identifier=dapur_aksesoris-dapur&sc=3439&user_id=0&rows=60&start=1&source=directory&device=desktop&page=1&related=true&st=product&safe_search=false', 'adParams': '&page=1&dep_id=3439&ob=23&ep=product&item=15&src=directory&device=desktop&user_id=0&minimum_item=15&start=1&no_autofill_range=5-14'}, 'query': 'query SearchProductQuery($params: String, $adParams: String) {\n  CategoryProducts: searchProduct(params: $params) {\n    count\n    data: products {\n      id\n      url\n      imageUrl: image_url\n      imageUrlLarge: image_url_700\n      catId: category_id\n      gaKey: ga_key\n      countReview: count_review\n      discountPercentage: discount_percentage\n      preorder: is_preorder\n      name\n      price\n      original_price\n      rating\n      wishlist\n      labels {\n        title\n        color\n        __typename\n      }\n      badges {\n        imageUrl: image_url\n        show\n        __typename\n      }\n      shop {\n        id\n        url\n        name\n        goldmerchant: is_power_badge\n        official: is_official\n        reputation\n        clover\n        location\n        __typename\n      }\n      labelGroups: label_groups {\n        position\n        title\n        type\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n  displayAdsV3(displayParams: $adParams) {\n    data {\n      id\n      ad_ref_key\n      redirect\n      sticker_id\n      sticker_image\n      productWishListUrl: product_wishlist_url\n      clickTrackUrl: product_click_url\n      shop_click_url\n      product {\n        id\n        name\n        wishlist\n        image {\n          imageUrl: s_ecs\n          trackerImageUrl: s_url\n          __typename\n        }\n        url: uri\n        relative_uri\n        price: price_format\n        campaign {\n          original_price\n          discountPercentage: discount_percentage\n          __typename\n        }\n        wholeSalePrice: wholesale_price {\n          quantityMin: quantity_min_format\n          quantityMax: quantity_max_format\n          price: price_format\n          __typename\n        }\n        count_talk_format\n        countReview: count_review_format\n        category {\n          id\n          __typename\n        }\n        preorder: product_preorder\n        product_wholesale\n        free_return\n        isNewProduct: product_new_label\n        cashback: product_cashback_rate\n        rating: product_rating\n        top_label\n        bottomLabel: bottom_label\n        __typename\n      }\n      shop {\n        image_product {\n          image_url\n          __typename\n        }\n        id\n        name\n        domain\n        location\n        city\n        tagline\n        goldmerchant: gold_shop\n        gold_shop_badge\n        official: shop_is_official\n        lucky_shop\n        uri\n        owner_id\n        is_owner\n        badges {\n          title\n          image_url\n          show\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      applinks\n      __typename\n    }\n    template {\n      isAd: is_ad\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n'}]
res = requests.post('https://gql.tokopedia.com/', headers=headers, data=payload)
```

Comment: Content length seems to be really different.

Comment: Also, instead fo the "data=payload" parameter try "json=payload".  I am not familiar with tokopedia or their API though.  And as @Crapy said, the content-length looks wierd.  Maybe take that out.

Comment: No this does not work. I sent a request using Chrome DevTools from the origin website, and the response was correct.

Comment: But the problem remains that how do I mock the origin as stated in the Request Headers?

Comment: Jesus Michaela's method suddenly works! Maybe it was because I stopped using my school's Wi-Fi, but the thing is it worked!

Answer (score 1):

[Status code 406 Not Acceptable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406) means server is unable to deliver response with what did you specify in proactive content negotiation headers and unwilling to serve default version. Said headers includes

- `Accept`
- `Accept-Charset`
- `Accept-Encoding`
- `Accept-Language`

If I am not mistaken your headers unlike Chrome's DevTools are missing `Accept-Language`.

Comment: No this does not work. I sent a request using Chrome DevTools from the origin website, and the response was correct.